# MySQL/MariaDB datetime virtual column shows wrong value when offset applied

Tags: mysql, mariadb

i've been wondering why sql query gives wrong value for a virtual column based on another column when offset is applied.

This is my table structure: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Ti0p.png)

My virtual column is `fix_expired_date`:

```
if(`expired_date` = '1900-01-01 00:00:00',NULL,`expired_date`)
```

I don't know how, but when i run this query: (this is just an example, in real app i run this instead `select * from ...`)

```
select a.*, if(`expired_date` = '1900-01-01 00:00:00',NULL,`expired_date`) from `inventory_detail_cached` a order by `client` asc, `brand` asc, `item_number` asc, `lot_number` asc limit 10 offset 11450
```

it gives wrong values instead of correct ones, in this screenshot, I run the query with the offset applied and select the same raw formula as the virtual column: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I2tOf.png)

is this because my system runs in mariadb instead of mysql?

System Information

```
Windows XAMPP

Server: 127.0.0.1 via TCP/IP
Server type: MariaDB
Server connection: SSL is not being used Documentation
Server version: 10.4.28-MariaDB - mariadb.org binary distribution
Protocol version: 10
User: root@localhost
Server charset: UTF-8 Unicode (utf8mb4)
```

Comment: Please add table definition and result of query as text.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your issue https://dbfiddle.uk/nlwB7GG_ ..What is your locale

Comment: Please edit your question to show (as text, not image) output of `show create table inventory_detail_cached`

Comment: 10.4 is quite old and only maintained for a few more months; you may be best off seeing if the problem still happens in the long term maintenance versions 10.11 or 10.6.  or at least in the newest 10.4 update.

Comment: `SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%zone%';  Are you working with DATETIME?  Or TIMESTAMP?